# Debugger catches an exception, but without debugger only toString triggers the exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.10.

```
ArrayList<AuthorEntity> getAuthorArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> authorsIds) {
    ArrayList<AuthorEntity> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Integer authorId : authorsIds) {
        try {
            AuthorEntity author = authorRepository.getById(authorId);
            // author.toString();
            result.add(author);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("EntityNotFoundException" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

If I uncomment toString(), the catch block works. If I comment the line out, catch block doesn't work (it is evidenced neither by breakpoint, nor by a printed message witnesses).

By the way, the debugger always shows that an exception is thrown if I evaluate the expression **authorRepository.getById(authorId)**.

Why is it like that? Maybe laziness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityNotFoundException will be thrown only if the code try to access a not existent entity. For example by calling any method on it. The correct way to check if the entity with the given id exists in the database is to use an Optional. Like:

```
Optional<AuthorEntity> check = authorRepository.getById(authorId);
if (check.isPresent() {
  // found
} else {
  // not found
}
```